# Base Negation given an inDigits

Tags: java, algorithm, math, design-patterns, twos-complement

I have the following problem:
Given an input in base (the input is given as an array of its digits in that base), write the negation of the number in "base's"-complement notatation in outDigits.
The "base's complement" notation of a number is a generalization of "two's complement": if we treat (-x) as an unsigned number in base and add it to x, we should get 0 (modulo base^digit-size). **I cannot call other function (even Math.pow)**
I keep getting an error with my tests. My code:

```
public static void baseNegate(int base, int[] inDigits, int[] outDigits) {
        outDigits[0] = 1;
        for (int i = outDigits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            outDigits[i] += base - (1 + inDigits[i]);
            if (i < outDigits.length - 1) {
                outDigits[i + 1] = outDigits[i] / base;
            }
            outDigits[i] %= base;
        }
    }
```

I cannot find the error in my calculations, please help.
my test:

```
------------------------------------ Negate number 365 in base 10 ------------------------------------
Test case have FAILED.
Base:    10
Input number:    [5, 6, 3]
Expected:        [5, 3, 6]
Output:          [5, 0, 0]

-------------------------------- Negate number b1010110011 in base 2 --------------------------------
Test case have FAILED.
Base:    2
Input number:    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
Expected:        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
Output:          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

-------------------------------------- Negate 0x7AF0 in base 16 --------------------------------------
Test case have FAILED.
Base:    16
Input number:    [0, 15, 10, 7]
Expected:        [0, 1, 5, 8]
Output:          [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You seem to have skipped a step, or at least not shown it. You've described what needs to be done. The next step is to define an algorithm, and reason why you think it works. Then, only after you've convinced yourself it's correct, you should reduce it to code. It will help us if you can add a high-level description of the algorithm with enough detail to evaluate its correctness and check that your code implements it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you may seem to be trying to do the negation of the complement while calculating the complement and it is complicating your solution.

You could try to simplify your solution by splitting it into two phases:

- First compute the complement.
- Second add the +1 to the computed complement.

The following method is a working version of this:

```java
    public static void baseNegate(int base, int[] inDigits, int[] outDigits) {
        // Compute the complement of the digits
        for (int i = outDigits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)  
            outDigits[i] = base - (1 + inDigits[i]);

        // Negate the complement by adding +1 to the computed number (collection of digits)
        for (int i = 0; i < outDigits.length; i++) {  
            if (outDigits[i] == base - 1) {
                // Max out digit. Set it to zero and try with the higher order next. 
                outDigits[i] = 0;
            } else {
                // Digit that has room for +1. Finally add the 1 and DONE!
                outDigits[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach is clearer, better performing and the code is self explanatory; but I added comments in the code to follow the logic used.

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a59081207)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can do it on the fly. OP was 99% there, was just iterating the wrong way. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59081215/5221149).

Answer (score 1):

Since the "expected" values show that index 0 is the lowest order digit, it means that for number `123₁₀` the array would be `[3, 2, 1]`, i.e. the digits are in reverse order of what you'd expect as a human. To a computer, it makes sense that value at index `i` is the value that must be multiplied by `baseⁱ`.

That means you need the `i` loop to iterate up, not down, so you can track the carry-over. Otherwise you code works fine:

```
public static void baseNegate(int base, int[] inDigits, int[] outDigits) {
    outDigits[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < outDigits.length; i++) { // <== reversed iteration
        outDigits[i] += base - (1 + inDigits[i]);
        if (i < outDigits.length - 1) {
            outDigits[i + 1] = outDigits[i] / base;
        }
        outDigits[i] %= base;
    }
}
```

Personally, writing it like this makes more sense, especially since it doesn't rely on `outDigits` array to be pre-initialized to all 0's:

```
public static void baseNegate(int base, int[] inDigits, int[] outDigits) {
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < outDigits.length; i++) {
        outDigits[i] = (base - inDigits[i] - carry) % base;
        carry = (inDigits[i] + outDigits[i] + carry) / base;
    }
}
```

For better performance, you don't want to use `%` and `/`, so something like this might be better:

```
public static void baseNegate(int base, int[] inDigits, int[] outDigits) {
    boolean carry = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < outDigits.length; i++) {
        if (carry) {
            outDigits[i] = base - inDigits[i] - 1;
        } else if (inDigits[i] != 0) {
            outDigits[i] = base - inDigits[i];
            carry = true;
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

All 3 will give the same result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(10, 5,6,3);
    test(2,  1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1);
    test(16, 0,15,10,7);
    test(8,  0,0,0); // 0 -> 0 (000)
    test(8,  1,0,0); // 1 -> -1 (777)
    test(8,  7,7,3); // 255 -> -255 (104)
    test(8,  0,0,4); // -256 -> -256 (004)
}

static void test(int base, int... inDigits) {
    int[] outDigits = new int[inDigits.length];
    baseNegate(base, inDigits, outDigits);
    System.out.printf("%d: %s -> %s%n", base, Arrays.toString(inDigits),
                                        Arrays.toString(outDigits));
}
```

*Output*

```
10: [5, 6, 3] -> [5, 3, 6]
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] -> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
16: [0, 15, 10, 7] -> [0, 1, 5, 8]
8: [0, 0, 0] -> [0, 0, 0]
8: [1, 0, 0] -> [7, 7, 7]
8: [7, 7, 3] -> [1, 0, 4]
8: [0, 0, 4] -> [0, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem around here:

```
if (i < outDigits.length - 1) {
    outDigits[i + 1] = outDigits[i] / base;
}
```

Let's say you're using base 10. Since a digit can only be 0 through 9, dividing by 10 would mean the result of this calculation is always 0. I don't think you intended this.